# Writing into another Spreadsheet with SetValue fails without errors/exceptions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a spreadsheet from a script running on another spreadsheet.

Nothing seems to have any effect on the table (`SetValue()`, `SetBackgroundRGB()`, etc.).
I've checked the scope, it includes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" permission; besides, this same script has no problem writing to another spreadsheet that it creates in runtime.

```js
function updateAnotheSpreadsheet() {
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<target spreadsheet id>');
  var sheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('<sheet name>');

  Browser.msgBox(sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()); // Here I see that my getSheetByName worked

  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue('Test value'); // But this does nothing
}
```

There are no errors but also no effect: nothing changes in the target spreadsheet.

Comment: Where is `cashFlow` defined? You're calling `cashFlow.getSheetByName()` in `var sheet` but as far as I can see this isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry, I tried to make the var names more 'generic' and missed this one! changing to targetSpreadsheet now.

Comment: Could you add a `Logger.log(sheet);` after you define it then include the log contents in the question? Just want to double check the script is finding the sheet correctly.

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: Ross: the Browser.msgBox line shows the correct content of the spreadsheet/sheet I'm trying to access, so yes, I double checked that -- unfortunately, not the problem.

Comment: Cooper: I'm afraid I can't, it a lot of sensitive financial information. But really easy to replicate as long as you have 2 spreadsheets of any kind.

Comment: Well if you can't give me a sterile sample of your data then I guess I can't help you. It's your responsibility to provide [mcve]

Comment: Cooper: you're right, I'm sorry. I created the spreadsheets to reproduce the error, see my comment under Mario's answer. Now I have the oauthScope problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was testing and was able to do what you are trying to do. You can try to declare a variable for the message, here is what I was able to do, I hope this resolves your inquiry.

```
function updateAnotherSpreadsheet() {      
      //Opening the second Spreadsheet by ID
      var targetSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<SpreadSheetId>");
      var sheet = targetSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("<SheetName>");
      //Getting the range to show on msgBox.
      var msg =  sheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValue();
      //Displaying old data on A1:A1 from the secondary Spreadsheet. 
      Browser.msgBox("Old data on secondary spreadsheet: " + msg);
      //Getting the range and setting new values
      sheet.getRange("A1:A1").setValue('Test value').setBackground("teal").setFontColor("white"); 
    }
```

I would suggest to check for more information here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

I hope this helps, greetings.

Comment: Hey Mario, thanks a lot for trying to help; unfortunately, the same thing happens with your code: the "Old data on secondary spreadsheet" displays the right value, however it's not updated (neither setValue nor background/fontcolor worked).

Comment: That is weird, I make the test and it worked. Check your sharing permissions, you can try to test with 2 different spreadsheets you create. My result was that it prompted the message on the 1st Spreadsheet and then made the change on the 2nd Spreadsheet.

Also you can try to openByUrl instead or make sure that the spreadsheet ID is the correct one.

Comment: I tried creating a clean testing spreadsheet:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17nJECBq-7KTJAKfPaj_U61n3ZnfQpuOx

but now I get the error:
You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets at updateAnotherSpreadsheet(Code:7) at onEdit(Code:2)

Comment: When you ran the script it required for authorization? you many need to create a custom menu and try again check this link to create a custom menu https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced for more details about the error.

I hope that works, make sure it request for authorization otherwise you will receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
A function called from OnEdit() can't ask for permissions. I needed to first update that other spreadsheet from any function called by something "active", like a button; then, after the script asks for permission once, it can do its thing from OnEdit() the next time it runs.